# in nginx return source as text

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, mime-types

I wish to be able to return `filename.jade` and `filename.styl` as text mime type.

`nginx` needs to serve anything in the `/source` directory as if it were text

right now using symlinks

```
/source/subdir/page1.jade.txt => ../subddir/page1.jade
```

and in `nginx`

```
location ~ ^/source/ {
  expires 1d;
  try_files $uri.txt 404;
}
```

this works, but not very elegant, and the symlinks need to be recreated

how is this accomplished purely in `nginx`?  is it necessary to use `rewrite` to chop off the `/source` directory from the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better for you to use specific `location` directive with `types` directive as example belove:

```
location ~ /*.jade {
   types          { }
   default_type   text/plain;
   try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ /*.styl {
   types          { }
   default_type    text/plain;
   try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Here for both `location` blocks you set to do not use any MIME-Types and to use as default `text/plain` MIME-Type so it should work for you.

Comment: works great - much better than my fake directory.  made a couple of minor changes - hope you don't mind.

Comment: didn't you miss `.` before `*` in each pattern? Anyway - changes are good :)

Comment: ouch!  need the detached directory.  the way it is not prevents `node.js` from rendering.  I think I need to keep `/source/` directory.